# Using AudioComponentCount in OSX CoreAudio

Tags: macos, core-audio

There were changes between 10.5 and 10.6 in the way AudioUnits are handled.  One of them (at least according to Apple's documentation) was the addition of Audio Component Services.  Among other places it is documented at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioComponentServicesReference/AudioComponentServicesReference.pdf

I'm putting together some code to handle input and output units, and am having trouble figuring out how to use these calls.  As a starting point I put in a call to AudioComponentCount, and the linker can't find it.  I've added CoreAudio.Framework and CoreAudioKit.Framework, but that does not help.  It is declared in AudioComponent.h.

Any suggestions on how to get this code to link properly?

Thanks for any help you can bring to bear on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look up `AudioComponentCount` in Xcode's documentation, it shows me a page entitled "[Audio Component Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)".  When I scroll to the top, it says it's from the AudioUnit framework. So, try linking against that.

Comment: Of course.  I feel a bit stupid for not having spotted that.  Question is answered.